# WSO2 APIM 3 docker persist API data

Tags: docker-compose, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I installed WSO2 APIM 3 using docker-compose, and created some APIs.  When I do a docker-compose down, and docker-compose up the API data is gone, how do I persist the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to mount storages for the databases and API Manager nodes. For APIM nodes, you need to mount APIM/repository/deployment/server folder to a volume. You can find details in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Common+Runtime+and+Configuration+Artifacts